# How to elegantly choose and apply a calibration function, maybe using ddply?

Tags: r, vectorization, plyr

I'm measuring many different chemical compounds, each of which has a different calibration curve, using a single instrument.  I'd like to apply the correct calibration curve, based on the name of the compound, to the raw data to the raw data from the instrument.  So, I start with a multiple calibration curves and a data frame of raw data:

```
#generate the calibration curves
x <- 1:10
calib.data.1 <- x+runif(10)
lm.1 <- lm(calib.data.1~x)
calib.data.2 <- 2*x+runif(10)
lm.2 <- lm(calib.data.2~x)
```

The raw data look like this:

```
compound <- factor(c("cpd1", "cpd2"))
values <- runif(2)
raw <- data.frame(compound, values)
```

It seems like the elegant way to choose the correct calibration curve would involve ddply or similar.  However I can't figure out how to do this without writing a function along these lines:

```
choose.calib <- function(raw, cpd)
    if(cpd=="cpd1"){
        calib=coef(lm.1)[1]+val*coef(lm.2)[2]
    }else{
    if(cpd=="cpd2"){
        calib=coef(lm.2)[1]+val*coef(lm.2)[2]
    }else{
        warning("no calib curve for compound")}}
    }
```

Then I would do something like

```
cal<-ddply(raw, .(compound), choose.calib)
```

(which doesn't work anyway due to my failure to understand if-else; but I think I can work that out on my own)

Is there a more vectorized way to do this?

Comment: I think the raw data should be `raw <- data.frame(compound, values)`, no?

Comment: Yep, thanks. Edited accordingly.

Comment: Shouldn't the first `calib` output use `coef(lm.1)[2]` rather than `coef(lm.2)[2]`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alternatively, you can create a `list` object that has your models, indexed by their compound type.  E.g. something like this should work:

```
 calibList <- list()
 calibList$cpd1 <- lm.1
 calibList$cpd2 <- lm.2

 choose.calib <- function(cpd, calibList){ return(calibList[[cpd]]) }
 predict.calib <- function(raw, cpd, calibList){
   predict(choose.calib(cpd, calibList), raw)
 }

 ddply(raw, predict.calib, cpd, calibList)
```

It's good to know the `predict.lm()` function, so that you needn't extract coefficients to "manually" do the prediction.

Answer (score 3):

One way that just jumps out at me is to create a coefficients data.frame containing a few fields, something like [cpd, intercept, coef]

You could then "join" your coefficients data.frame to your starting data.frame using `merge()` then you'd have your calibration coefficients in the same data frame.

Here's a simple example using your data:

```
x <- 1:10
calib.data.1 <- x+runif(10)
lm.1 <- lm(calib.data.1~x)
lm1coef <- data.frame(compound="cpd1", t(lm.1$coefficients))
names(lm1coef) <- c("compound","intercept","b1")

calib.data.2 <- 2*x+runif(10)
lm.2 <- lm(calib.data.2~x)
lm2coef <- data.frame(compound="cpd2",t(lm.2$coefficients))
names(lm2coef) <- c("compound","intercept","b1")

coefs <- rbind(lm1coef, lm2coef)

compound <- factor(c("cpd1", "cpd2"))
values <- runif(2)
raw <- data.frame(compound, values)

raw2 <- merge(raw, coefs)
```

Clearly you could make the bit that extracts the coefficients into a function. But this gives you the gist.